# Dependency check for python OWASP

Tags: python, plugins, owasp

Is there a dependency check plugin for the python files to be scanned? i see maven plugin that which helps to scan jar files. similar to that do we have anything for python

Comment: The [first result on google](https://pyup.io/safety/) for "python dependency vulnerability scanner" looks promising